# Restricting codomain of dominant map $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ of varieties to get a finite map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the fairly common set-up: Suppose you have a dominant map $\varphi\colon X\to Y$ of irreducible varieties, and the field extension of rational function fields $k(Y)/k(X)$ is finite, here $k$ being the algebraically closed field.

I'm wondering, is it always possible to find a nonempty open set $U$ in $Y$ such that the restriction map $$
\varphi|_{\varphi^{-1}(U)}\colon \varphi^{-1}(U)\to U
$$
is finite?

Comment: Yes, lemma 28.47.4 here http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02NV